# Why is my ASP.NET GridView failing to update one cell?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, webforms

I have an ASP.NET GridView that I'm using to display data from a database. I want the user to be able to edit the rows after they have been submitted (in case there were errors in the submission). Users are able to edit everything except for one cell. Here is the markup for the GridView and the SqlDataSource to which it is bound:

```
<asp:GridView runat="server" ID="Gv_Assignments" AutoGenerateColumns="False" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="True" AutoGenerateEditButton="True"
                    DataKeyNames="ID" DataSourceID="sds_GvAssignments" EmptyDataText="No assignments have been created.">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID" InsertVisible="False" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="ID" />
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LessonName" SortExpression="LessonName">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEditLessonName" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LessonName") %>' runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_LessonName" DataTextField="lessonname" DataValueField="lessonname"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLessonName" runat="server" ErrorMessage="LessonName is a required field."
                                    ControlToValidate="ddlEditLessonName" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource_LessonName" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DedicatedTerminal_devConnectionString %>'
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [lessonname] FROM [_YTD_Master] where loc <> 'All' AND lessonname <> '' order by lessonname"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LessonName") %>' ID="LblLessonName"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="LessonID"  HeaderText="LessonID" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="LessonID" />--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LessonID" SortExpression="LessonID">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LessonID") %>' ID="lblLessonID"></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LessonID") %>' ID="Label30x"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="StartDate" SortExpression="StartDate">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' ID="txtEditDateFrom"></asp:TextBox>
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEditDateFrom" />
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvStartDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Start Date is a required field."
                                    ControlToValidate="txtEditDateFrom" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("StartDate") %>' ID="Label3"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EndDate" SortExpression="EndDate">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:TextBox runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndDate") %>' ID="txtEditDateTo"></asp:TextBox>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvEndDate" runat="server" ErrorMessage="End Date is a required field."
                                    ControlToValidate="txtEditDateTo" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender runat="server" TargetControlID="txtEditDateTo" />
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("EndDate") %>' ID="Label4"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LocationCode" SortExpression="LocationCode">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:DropDownList ID="Ddl_EditLocCode" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>' runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource_EditLocCode" DataTextField="location_code" DataValueField="location_code"></asp:DropDownList>
                                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvLocCode" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Location Code is a required field."
                                    ControlToValidate="Ddl_EditLocCode" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                                <asp:SqlDataSource runat="server" ID="SqlDataSource_EditLocCode" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DedicatedTerminal_devConnectionString %>'
                                    SelectCommand="SELECT DISTINCT [location_code] FROM [comcheck_locations] order by location_code asc"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("LocationCode") %>' ID="Label5"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                        <%--<asp:BoundField DataField="DateAssigned" HeaderText="DateAssigned" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="DateAssigned" />--%>
                        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="DateAssigned" SortExpression="DateAssigned">
                            <EditItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateAssigned") %>' ID="lblDateAssigned"></asp:Label>
                            </EditItemTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("DateAssigned") %>' ID="Label12"></asp:Label>
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>

                    </Columns>
                                   </asp:GridView>
```

The SqlDataSource:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sds_GvAssignments" runat="server" ConnectionString='<%$ ConnectionStrings:DedicatedTerminal_devConnectionString %>' 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [_CreatedAssignments] WHERE [ID] = @ID" 
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [_CreatedAssignments] ([LessonName], [LessonID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [LocationCode], 
                    [DateAssigned]) VALUES (@LessonName, @LessonID, @StartDate, @EndDate, @LocationCode, @DateAssigned)" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT [ID], [LessonName], [LessonID], [StartDate], [EndDate], [LocationCode], [DateAssigned] 
                    FROM [_CreatedAssignments]" UpdateCommand="UPDATE [_CreatedAssignments] SET [LessonName] = @LessonName, 
                    [LessonID] = @LessonID, [StartDate] = @StartDate, [EndDate] = @EndDate, [LocationCode] = @LocationCode, 
                    [DateAssigned] = @DateAssigned WHERE [ID] = @ID">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonID" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="StartDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EndDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LocationCode" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="DateAssigned" Type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonName" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LessonID" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="StartDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter DbType="Date" Name="EndDate"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LocationCode" Type="String"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="DateAssigned" Type="DateTime"></asp:Parameter>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="ID" Type="Int32"></asp:Parameter>
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

When the user edits the "Lesson Name" field, the "LessonID" should update automatically when the row is updated. Each lesson name has a unique ID that should be reflected both on the front and back ends. Every other field updates just like it is supposed to, but the "LessonID" field fails to update. Have I missed something in the markup? Here is the `RowUpdating` code that I'm using to make this change:

```
Private Sub Gv_Assignments_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles Gv_Assignments.RowUpdating
        'change the lessonID to the appropriate ID based on the lesson name
        'get the lesson name, then set the label text in the lesson ID column to the correct ID by calling GetLessonID(lessonname)

        Dim lessonNameBox As DropDownList = DirectCast(Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("ddlEditLessonName"), DropDownList)
        Dim lessonIdLabel As TextBox = DirectCast(Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).FindControl("LblLessonID"), TextBox)
        Dim ID As Integer = Integer.Parse(Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(1).Text)
        lessonIdLabel.Text = GetLessonID(lessonNameBox.SelectedValue)

        'Gv_Assignments.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(3).Text = GetLessonID(lessonNameBox.SelectedValue)
        UpdateLessonID(lessonIdLabel.Text, ID)
    End Sub

    Protected Sub UpdateLessonID(lessonID As String, ID As Integer)
        Try
            Dim conn As New Connection
            Using conn.Conn
                conn.Conn.Open()
                Using cmd As New SqlCommand
                    With cmd
                        .Connection = conn.Conn
                        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
                        '.CommandText = "update dbo.CreatedAssignments set LessonName = 'test' where "
                        .CommandText = "update dbo.CreatedAssignments Set LessonID = " & "'" & lessonID & "'" & " where ID = " & ID
                    End With
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End Using
            End Using
        Catch ex As Exception
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, [GetType](), "updateError", "alert('LessonID could not be updated. Please try again.');", True)
        End Try
    End Sub
```

In a nutshell, the "LessonID" fails to update when the user updates the "LessonName" field. Every other field updates correctly. "LessonID" should be **ReadOnly**. I want the update to happen in the background. The user should not be able to edit this value. Does my problem have something to do with the fact that "LessonID" is a `Asp:Label`? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Using <asp:SqlDataSource ..> is considered a super bad practice, imagine if you need to change your database.. DON'T DO IT

Comment: @DiegoS What is a better alternative?

Comment: you should keep separation between your presentation layer and your database layer.. i would suggest you to use .DataSource attribute on server side, which receives data obtained from another "DataAccess" layer..